# Django, unit test for SOA style sites without data contract

Tags: django, testing, contract

Let's say I have 2 django projects within the company, A and B, B consumes data from A via a restful API, and it doesn't have WADLs

Originally my unit test (more like a functional test) consumes data directly from A, but it poses a lot of issues to run in integration server like Jenkins.

To solve it, I will need to create some fake data to feed into project B (you can say this is the proper way of unit testing).

Now another problem raised is, A might change the critical data structure and B continues to pass unit tests with mocked data.

So before I go ahead do anything, I would like to ask: how would you do it?

Comment: I am pondering an approach simulates data contract, by making both apps agree on a python class(data contract) that resides in a third place, so both app on unit tests will convert json into the agreed python class object for verification.

Answer (score 0):

Have your test suite for A record the data that comes back - run B's tests afterwards, using the generated data from A's test suite as input.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly with fixtures and a custom test runner.  It depends on how models between a and b differ and how easily you can convert between the formats for each.